# Writing hashcode for JPA entities

Tags: jpa-2.0, hashcode

I am a little confused about the rule while making hashcodes for my JPA2 entities.

I have an embedded entity comprising audit columns (lastModifiedDate, createdDate) etc. Should this object pe part of the hashcode for my entity ?

```
@Entity(name = "CaseStatusEnum")
public class CaseStatus implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5936623582710348810L;

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true,nullable=false,length=30)
    private String caseStatus;

    @Column(nullable=false,length=100)
    private String caseStatusDesc;

    @Embedded
    private AuditTrail auditTrail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you this link to overview concepts around the equals and hashcode function, specially its use within the diferents implementations of Hash and Collections.
[overriding equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
Then you maybe need to adjust the implementation of equals and hashcode functions depending on the JPA2 implementation you are using. Whatever be, I recommend you to take a look at this article about [Hibernate - equals and hashcode](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) to a better understanding of how could your app could be affected overriding this functions.

Regards